# Method substitution between objects

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, oop

In nodejs, typescript, I want to substitute a method of an object with a method of another object; I have written the following very simple example to better understand my problem (the real situation is, more or less, the same):

```
export default class A_01 {
  constructor(private variableA1: string) {}

  public writeSomething() {
    console.log(`${this.variableA1} from class A`);
  }
}
```

```
import A_01 from "./oop_class_A";

export default class B_01 extends A_01 {
  constructor(private variableB1: string) {
    super(variableB1);
  }

  public writeSomething() {
    console.log(`${this.variableB1} from class B`);
  }
}
```

```
import A_01 from "./oop_class_A";
class C_01 {
  constructor() {}

  run() {
    return new A_01("Object A_01 from class C_01"); // cannot modify this object creation!!!
  }
}
```

```
import A_01 from "./oop_class_A";
import B_01 from "./oop_class_B";

const D_01 = new A_01("from_class_D_01");

D_01.writeSomething();
```

So, how to print from_class_D_01 from **class B** (and NOT from class A) ? 
I have tried casting

```
const D_01 = new A_01("from_class_D_01") as B_01
```

but it's only a type and I lose it at runtime.

Comment: `B_01.prototype.writeSomething.call(D_01)` will call the function such that `D_01` is the value of `this`. Note that the constructed `D_01` object has no "variableB1" property.

Comment: It sounds a bit like you're approaching an OOP problem in a non-OOP way? Why would you want to use a method from class B after instantiating class A ? There must be a OOP design pattern other than inheritance that is better suited to your problem.

Comment: @Kokodoko I have to modify an old Angular project; I have to find a solution or I will have to change a lot of code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this is what you need, this is a very hacky way to overwrite the `writeSomething` method after an A_01 instance has been created.

```
const D_01 = new A_01("from_class_D_01")
D_01.writeSomething = B_01.prototype.writeSomething
D_01.writeSomething()
```

Now it will write "from class B" even though it's an instance of A_01

Comment: Instead of printing "from_class_D_01 from class A" it prints "undefined from class B", but this because there is the variableB1 in the B_01' writeSomething method.

Comment: You'd have to overwrite that variable too (or give them the same name in the class)... But this kind of hacking can quickly lead to unexpected results... making an already messy old angular project even messier...

Comment: yes, you are right; we are planning to entirely rewrite the project.